# Detect window or form defocus

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How can i detect a window change (or form defocus)?

I have 1 picturebox, & 1 label (not visible)  above the picturebox with text "UNAUTHORIZED COPY" 
the question is: **how to make it visible if the window, or form gets defocused or when the user open another program.** But Focus is property for "controls" but not for forms, then there is not easy way.

Additionally my program already clear the clipboard when detect the printscreen key to avoid the most common snapshot from any windows user, i just want to add now this watermark text for use of third party screen capture software.

Comment: ***Deactivate** Occurs when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form.*  Can you guess what the counterpart is named?

Comment: And then they will just take a photo with their phone...

Comment: @ZoharPeled   but not the official hires scan/ professional pictures...

They can shot a photo of the screen and for most of the people in very bad angle or medium quality due camera or display (i hope), the main program function is tagging groupal photos as facebook does with transparent rectangles and 'mousehover' function to show the names...
and after your reflection maybe i must delete the zoom mode! or limit the image if screen resolution is high... just for avoid 4k displays and higher.. if its lower size full resolution available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if the form lost focus, use Deactivate in the events

Double click on your form, and go to the right side where it says: "**Load**". Click on the "**Load**" text and search for a event called: "**Deactivate**", click on that and the following code has entered in your code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate

End Sub
```

I hope it helped!

EDIT: Thanks to LarsTech for pointing out that LostFocus is only used when updating UICues or when writing custom controls. ([Control.LostFocus Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: From [Control.LostFocus Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx): `Instead the Enter and Leave events should be used for all controls except the Form class, which uses the Activated and Deactivate events.`